# How to use a newer version of gcc on ubuntu?

Tags: gcc, ubuntu-18.04

I am running ubuntu 18.04 and I currently have:

```
(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@user:~$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5

(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@user:~$ gcc-8 --version
gcc-8 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1) 8.3.0

(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@user:~$ which gcc
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/bin/gcc
```

I am trying to use the latest `gcc-8` as show [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028601/install-gcc-8-only-on-ubuntu-18-04). However when I run

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-8 800 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-8
```

I get the following error:

> update-alternatives: error: alternative g++ can't be slave of gcc: it
>   is a master alternative

When I try:

```
(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@user:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

I get another error:

> update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for gcc

How is it that I do not have alternative for `gcc`? Any suggestions on how I can resolve this error and configure `gcc-8` to be the default gcc installation would be appreciated.

---

Running `which gcc` from outside the conda environment does not return anything:

```
ubuntu@user:~$ which gcc
ubuntu@user:~$
```

but

```
ubuntu@user:~$ gcc-8 --version
gcc-8 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1) 8.3.0
```

---

Update. I'm trying the following as per the helpful suggestion below, but still to no avail.

```
(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@user:~$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-8 40
(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@user:~$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8 60
(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@user:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config g++
There are 3 choices for the alternative g++ (providing /usr/bin/g++).

  Selection    Path                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-7   100       auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/g++-4.8                  60        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/g++-8                    40        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-7   100       manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/g++-8 to provide /usr/bin/g++ (g++) in manual mode
```

So far so good, but when I test the g++ version, it's still the same!

```
~$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.5
```

Comment: You need to set a specific gcc executable as an alternative to gcc and a specific g++ executable as an alternative to g++, never mix them and do not use `--slave`. Use two separate `update-alternatives` commands, one for gcc and one for g++.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Updated my question

Comment: You are using the `gcc` provided by anaconda, not the one installed from the ubuntu repositories. As you are saying the problem is not presents outside the conda environment. So I guess you should be asking how to upgrade to a newer gcc version in anaconda.

Comment: You're right, I asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59015125/how-to-make-conda-use-default-gcc. Completely stuck on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible you arrived because something blew up with nvidia.
(I'm on cudatoolkit 11.4 and actually downgrading got me out of trouble - your mileage may vary.)

```
sudo apt install gcc-9 g++-9
sudo mkdir /usr/local/cuda/bin
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-9 /usr/local/cuda/bin/gcc
```

WARNING - I recommend using timeshift to make a backup of your working system.
https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift

This will get you the latest gcc 11

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu hirsute main universe'
sudo apt-get install g++-11
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-11 100
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-11 50
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-11 100
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-11 50
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cpp cpp-bin /usr/bin/cpp-11 100
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cpp cpp-bin /usr/bin/cpp-11 50
sudo update-alternatives --set g++ /usr/bin/g++-11
sudo update-alternatives --set gcc /usr/bin/gcc-11
sudo update-alternatives --set cpp-bin /usr/bin/cpp-11
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11-20210417-1ubuntu1) 11.0.1 20210417
```

Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: When setting the gcc version alternative to contain 11, shouldent the first command contain the old version? eg. `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-11 100
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-11 50` to `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-11 100
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-9 50`